# Exclude prefix to all lines in a column (R software)

Tags: r, prefix

I would like to exclude a common prefix to all lines from a specific collumn in R dataframe. My input:

```
   chr

   chr1
   chr2
   chr3
   chr4
```

And my expected output:

```
  chr
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are factors then you need to change the 'level' names rather than working on the item values:

```
chrdf <- read.table(text="chr1
    chr2
    chr3
    chr4", col.names="chr")
chrdf
#--------
   chr
1 chr1
2 chr2
3 chr3
4 chr4

levels(chrdf$chr) <- gsub("chr", "", levels(chrdf$chr) )
chrdf
  chr
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

The 'factor' variable-type is a source of difficulty for many people. I can testify that the difficulty persists for quite a while. I don't ask a lot of questions, but one that I did ask got a lot of upvotes from the rest of the similarly confused (or perhaps the smarter ones were only bemused and sympathetic) SO readership.

Comment: I don't quite see why this is necessary. Just to maintain the `factor` class of the "chr" column?

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy using `gsub`:

```
x <- c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4")
gsub("chr", "", x)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

You may also consider the `substring` function.

```
substring(x, 4, nchar(x))
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning how to convert that to numbers rather than strings

Comment: @JuliánUrbano, I wouldn't want to overdo it with stating the obvious, but feel free to edit :-)

Comment: It could be troublesome later if he needs them as integers.

Comment: I think that the obvious will be necessary to me... =/

Comment: Actually I need to convert this now, after, in my next steps, i will add the prefix again...

Comment: `chr <- paste0("chr", 1:4)`, `as.numeric(gsub("chr", "", chr))`